# Galois Group over Ring of Integers

Tags: number-theory, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose we have a quadratic (Galois) extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, call it $k$ with Galois group $G$.  If we look at the ring of integers inside of $k$, call it $\mathcal{O}_k$, is it true that $\mathcal{O}_k$ is stable under $G$? That is, do we have that $\sigma x\in\mathcal{O}_k$ for every $x\in \mathcal{O}_k$ and $\sigma\in G$?

I don't even really know what the routes are that someone would take to look at such a question.  I guess this is probably true since elements of the ring of integers are solutions to certain (monic) polynomials with integer coefficients, so the galois group would just change to a different solution of the polynomial, hence remaining in $\mathcal{O}_k$?

Comment: On second thought, this shouldn't be hard to prove...

Comment: Your second paragraph is exactly the right approach :) It works for the ring of integers in any number field, too.

Comment: Okay yeah, thanks.  Just didn't want to get my hands dirty, but this all works out rather nicely.

Comment: For the general case, there's the [normal basis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis) and the important question of *normal integral basis*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_integral_basis#Galois_module_structure_of_algebraic_integers.

Comment: A related fact is that Galois will (transitively) permute the primes above a given rational prime.

Comment: May I recommend that you write up (and accept) the answer to your own question? This may seem like a strange idea, but it is entirely acceptable behavior.

Comment: Some people, including yours truly make a living off the fact that the Galois group acts on the ring of integers (and accordingly also on the units therein). Understanding the structure of these $G$-modules is an old and exciting problem, and there is plenty of work left (in a sense, we have barely started).

Comment: @JBeardz: To prevent this from going off unanswered, and since you figured out the answer on your own, why not post the answer and proof as an answer to your own question?

Comment: Sorry, I will.  Is there any rush?

Comment: @JBeardz Rush or not... Any chance of your commitment ("I will") ever being coined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove a more general theorem:

> Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ of $\Bbb Q$, and let $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}$ be the [ring of integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RingofIntegers.html) of $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, i.e. the algebraic integers, i.e. roots of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Then, $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}$ is invariant under the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$.

Let $x$ be an element of $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}$. Then, it satisfies a monic polynomial $f \in \Bbb Z[X]$. Let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$. Since $\sigma$ is a field automorphism, in particular a ring homomorphism, we have $f(\sigma(x)) = \sigma(f(x))$. Since $f(x) = 0$, we have $f(\sigma(x)) = 0$, i.e. $\sigma(x)$ is also a root of $f$. Since $f$ is monic, it follows that $\sigma(x) \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}$, so the theorem is proved.